# Algorithm to generate 1000 distinct integers in the range [0,8000]?

Tags: algorithm, random, permutation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do you efficiently generate a list of K non-repeating integers between 0 and an upper bound N](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/158716/how-do-you-efficiently-generate-a-list-of-k-non-repeating-integers-between-0-and)

What are some alternative methods to generate 1000 distinct random integers in the range [0,8000] as opposed to the following:

1. naive method: generating a number and checking if it's already in the array. O(n^2)
2. linear shuffle: generate sequence 0 to 8000, shuffle, take the first 1000. O(n)

Comment: How is the first method 'naive'? Checking if it is in the array makes it NOT RANDOM. If it is random, DUPLICATES ARE EXPECTED.

Comment: method 1 would be ok if you use a set instead of an array.

Comment: duplicates: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/196017/unique-random-numbers-in-o1 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/158716/how-do-you-efficiently-generate-a-list-of-k-non-repeating-integers-between-0-and-n

Comment: @Coronatus Are you suggesting it's impossible to randomly select 1000 from 8000 without replacement? If you can show how method 1 is statistically biased, please do.

Comment: Where do you get the O(n^2) in the first case? Each number needs to be tried `m` times, where `m` is geometrically distributed. This means that the complexity is worse.

Comment: for(i=0;i<1000;i++) print i;



(this is a joke, of course)

Comment: You need to check, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, ..., n times. 1+2+3+...+n = n(n+1)/2 = O(n^2)

Comment: @The Last Ninja: You need to check again until you get a new number. This means that you need to run through the list a geometrically distributed number of times for each new number. I don't know how to simplify the sum to find the answer, but I think it is O(n^3).

Comment: The problem with method one is that how long it takes is depends on how your number generating function works.  If you are doing something like rand()%8001 you may end up getting in a situation where the period is less than 1000 and you are now in an infinite loop.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use a partial [Fisher-Yates shuffle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle) implemented using swaps. One of the nice features of this algorithm is that if you stop after `k` swaps, the first `k` numbers are a random sample of size `k` from the complete set.

Comment: +1. I was going to suggest just shuffling the whole array; for some reason this obvious optimisation didn't occur to me.

Comment: Problem is that you still need to create an array from [0,8000].  Can you create a permutation without the overhead?  What if you wanted 10 unique numbers between 1..1,000,000?

Comment: Technically you could make it a sparse array implemented as a dict instead, and any position which doesn't have a value set is simply taken to be equal to its index.

Comment: @Dav: Good suggestion. This would save the O(n) construction of the list of integers from [0, 8000].

Comment: I don't recall mentioning anything about a bitarray?

Comment: @Dav: (great idea: was doing something along those lines for this and in general, k-permutations: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2394246/algorithm-to-select-a-single-random-combination-of-values/2394308#2394308)

Answer (score 2):

You could create a list containing the numbers 0 to 8000.

Then looping 1000 times generate a random number between 0 and the length of the list.

Remove that element from the list and add it to an output list.

By removing the element you ensure that your selections are unique.

```
while (outputList.Count < 1000)
{
    index = random.Next(0, inputList.Count);
    outputList.Add(inputList[index]);
    inputList.RemoveAt(index);
}
```

Comment: This will run in O(n^2) since RemoveAt for a vector or array is O(n).

Answer (score 1):

This is from Knuth's the Art of Programming (via Jon Bentley's Programming Pearls), implemented in Python:

```
import random

# randomly select m numbers from n candidates    
def random_select(m, n):
    select = m
    result = []
    for i in xrange(n):
        if random.randint(0, n-i) < select:
            result.append(i)
            select -= 1
    return result

random_select(1000, 8000)
```

this will generate a list of random numbers in numerical order.  It works by iterating over all the integers from 0-n (i.e 0-8000), and randomly selecting them with a probability of(number left to select / number of remaining candidates).  It runs in O(n), so do not try it if n is very large compared to m - e.g. selecting ten numbers out of a billion.  It uses no memory other than the result list (m) and a few local variables, unlike solutions that rely on shuffling a list of length n.

If you want the result in a random order then shuffle the list afterwards.

Comment: The Pythonic variant: import random; random.sample(xrange(8000), 1000)

Answer (score 1):

Partial Fisher-Yates, as [@Mark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2576023/algorithm-to-generate-1000-distinct-integers-in-the-range-0-8000/2576028#2576028) has suggested, with a little twist, storing the swaps along the way.
This way, it will *at most* consume as much memory as the result list O(m).
It will also run in O(m) - not O(n), as other solutions that enumerate the whole range - so it should not have problems on larger ranges.
This way, you can have the best of both worlds.

```
/// <summary>
/// Generates unique random numbers
/// <remarks>
/// Worst case memory usage is O(min((emax-imin)/2, num))
/// </remarks>
/// </summary>
/// <param name="random">Random source</param>
/// <param name="imin">Inclusive lower bound</param>
/// <param name="emax">Exclusive upper bound</param>
/// <param name="num">Number of integers to generate</param>
/// <returns>Sequence of unique random numbers</returns>
public static IEnumerable<int> UniqueRandoms(
    Random random, int imin, int emax, int num)
{
    int dictsize = num;
    long half = (emax - (long)imin + 1) / 2;
    if (half < dictsize)
        dictsize = (int)half;
    Dictionary<int, int> trans = new Dictionary<int, int>(dictsize);
    for (int i = 0; i < num; i++)
    {
        int current = imin + i;
        int r = random.Next(current, emax);
        int right;
        if (!trans.TryGetValue(r, out right))
        {
            right = r;
        }
        int left;
        if (trans.TryGetValue(current, out left))
        {
            trans.Remove(current);
        }
        else
        {
            left = current;
        }
        if (r > current)
        {
            trans[r] = left;
        }
        yield return right;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## Sorted list with no sort, O(n)

If you want the integers sorted, I got to this answer in [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1866031/generating-sorted-random-ints-without-the-sort) with a lot of help. You can do it using an exponential variate and thereby **avoid any sort**. As a result it is O(n):

From [Alok's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1866031/generating-sorted-random-ints-without-the-sort/1866177#1866177) and [Dan Dyer's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1866031/generating-sorted-random-ints-without-the-sort/1866055#1866055) it turns out that using an [exponential distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_distribution) for a set of deltas gives a uniform distribution of integers in sequence.

So, you just start generating numbers and then scale them at the end. Adding 1 to the delta ensures you never repeat a value.

```
import random,sys,math

def genSortedInts(mini,maxi,vals):
    running = 0
    deltas = [random.expovariate(1.0) for i in range(0,vals+1)]
    floats = []
    for d in deltas:
        running += d
        floats.append(running)
    upper = floats.pop()
    valRange = maxi-mini-(vals-1)
    ints = [mini+int(f/upper*valRange)+id for id,f in enumerate(floats)]
    return ints

if __name__ == "__main__":
    vals = 10
    maxi = 80
    mini = 0
    print(genSortedInts(mini,maxi,vals))
```

Note the use of `random.expovariate(1.0)`, a [Python exponential distribution random number generator](http://docs.python.org/library/random.html#random.expovariate) (very useful!). Here it's called with a mean of 1.0 (arg is 1/mean), but since the script normalises against the last number in the sequence, the mean itself doesn't matter.

Output (fair dice roll) for 10 values up to 80:

```
[3, 5, 10, 16, 25, 37, 41, 45, 57, 70]
```