# Randomly selecting letters by frequency of use

Tags: perl, random

After feeding few Shakespeare books to my Perl script I have a hash with 26 english letters as keys and the number of their occurences in texts - as value:

```
%freq = (
    a => 24645246,
    b => 1409459,
    ....
    z => 807451,
);
```

and of course the total number of all letters - let's say in the `$total` variable.

Is there please a nice trick to generate a string holding 16 random letters (a letter can occur several times there) - weighted by their frequency of use?

To be used in a word game similar to Ruzzle:

[image]

Something elegant - like picking a random line from a file, as suggested by a [Perl Cookbook](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596003135.do) receipt:

```
rand($.) < 1 && ($line = $_) while <>;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Perl Cookbook trick for picking a random line (which can also be found in [perlfaq5](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq5.html#How-do-I-select-a-random-line-from-a-file%3f)) can be adapted for weighted sampling too:

```
my $chosen;
my $sum = 0;
foreach my $item (keys %freq) {
    $sum += $freq{$item};
    $chosen = $item if rand($sum) < $freq{$item};
}
```

Here, `$sum` corresponds to the line counter `$.` and `$freq{$item}` to the constant `1` in the Cookbook version.

---

If you're going to be picking a lot of weighted random samples, you can speed this up a bit with some preparation (note that this destroys `%freq`, so make a copy first if you want to keep it):

```
# first, scale all frequencies so that the average frequency is 1:
my $avg = 0;
$avg += $_ for values %freq;
$avg /= keys %freq;
$_ /= $avg for values %freq;

# now, prepare the array we'll need for fast weighted sampling:
my @lookup;
while (keys %freq) {
    my ($lo, $hi) = (sort {$freq{$a} <=> $freq{$b}} keys %freq)[0, -1];
    push @lookup, [$lo, $hi, $freq{$lo} + @lookup];
    $freq{$hi} -= (1 - $freq{$lo});
    delete $freq{$lo};
}
```

Now, to draw a random weighted sample from the prepared distribution, you just do this:

```
my $r = rand @lookup;
my ($lo, $hi, $threshold) = @{$lookup[$r]};
my $chosen = ($r < $threshold ? $lo : $hi);
```

(This is basically the Square Histogram method described in Marsaglia, Tsang & Wang (2004), ["Fast Generation of Discrete Random Variables"](http://www.jstatsoft.org/v11/i03/paper), *J. Stat. Soft.* 11(3) and originally due to A.J. Walker (1974).)

Comment: Should I always run through the whole loop OR call `last` if the `if` is true?

Comment: @AlexanderFarber: You should always run through the whole loop, since the chosen item may (and usually will) change several times during the loop.

Answer (score 5):

I have no clue about Perl syntax so I'll just write pseudo-code. You can do something like that

```
sum <= 0
foreach (letter in {a, z})
  sum <= sum + freq[letter]
pick r, a random integer in [0, sum[ 
letter <= 'a' - 1
do
  letter <= letter + 1
  r <= r - freq(letter)
while r > 0

letter is the resulting value
```

The idea behind this code is to make a stack of boxes for each letter. The size of each box is the frequency of the letter. Then we choose a random location on this stack and see which letter's box we landed.

Example :

```
freq(a) = 5
freq(b) = 3
freq(c) = 3
sum = 11

|    a    |  b  |  c  | 
 - - - - - - - - - - -
```

When we choose a 0 <= r < 11, we have the following probabilities

- Pick a 'a' = 5 / 11
- Pick a 'b' = 3 / 11
- Pick a 'c' = 3 / 11

Which is exactly what we want.

Comment: Thanks, this makes sense. But I suspect there might be some kind of `rand(1/$total)` way too...

Answer (score 2):

You can first built a table of the [running sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Running_total) of the frequency. So if you have the following data:

```
%freq = (
    a => 15,
    b => 25,
    c => 30,
    d => 20
);
```

the running sum would be;

```
%running_sums = (
    a => 0,  
    b => 15, 
    c => 40, # 15 + 25
    d => 70, # 15 + 25 + 30
);
$max_sum = 90; # 15 + 25 + 30 + 20
```

To pick a single letter with the weighted frequency, you need to select a number between `[0,90)`, then you can do a linear search on the running_sum table for the range that includes the letter. For example, if your random number is 20 then the appropriate range is 15-40, which is for the letter 'b'. Using linear search gives a total running time of `O(m*n)` where m is the number of letters we need and n is the size of the alphabet (therefore m=16, n=26). This is essentially what @default locale do.

Instead of linear search, you can also do a binary search on the running_sum table to get the closest number rounded down. This gives a total running time of `O(m*log(n))`.

For picking m letters though, there is a faster way than `O(m*log(n))`, perticularly if `n < m`. First you generate `m` random numbers in sorted order ([which can be done without sorting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1866031/generating-sorted-random-ints-without-the-sort-on) in `O(n)`) then you do a linear matching for the ranges between the list of sorted random numbers and the list of running sums. This gives a total runtime of `O(m+n)`. [The code in its entirety running in Ideone](http://ideone.com/73JhvT).

```
use List::Util qw(shuffle);

my %freq = (...);

# list of letters in sorted order, i.e. "a", "b", "c", ..., "x", "y", "z"
# sorting is O(n*log(n)) but it can be avoided if you already have 
# a list of letters you're interested in using
my @letters = sort keys %freq;

# compute the running_sums table in O(n)
my $sum = 0;
my %running_sum;
for(@letters) {
    $running_sum{$_} = $sum;
    $sum += $freq{$_};
}

# generate a string with letters in $freq frequency in O(m)
my $curmax = 1;
my $curletter = $#letters;
my $i = 16; # the number of letters we want to generate
my @result;
while ($i > 0) {
    # $curmax generates a uniformly distributed decreasing random number in [0,1)
    # see http://repository.cmu.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=3483&context=compsci
    $curmax = $curmax * (1-rand())**(1. / $i);

    # scale the random number $curmax to [0,$sum)
    my $num = int ($curmax * $sum);

    # find the range that includes $num
    while ($num < $running_sum{$letters[$curletter]}) {
        $curletter--;
    }

    push(@result, $letters[$curletter]);

    $i--;
}

# since $result is sorted, you may want to use shuffle it first
# Fisher-Yates shuffle is O(m)
print "", join('', shuffle(@result));
```